# Using a IIR filter with python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, signal-processing

I'm trying to filter this ECG signal (with a 2Hz noise), using IIR Filter on python and so far I have this.

```py
data = np.loadtxt('ecg_lfn.dat')
fs=1000
b, a = ss.iirfilter(3, 2/(.5*fs), rs=60, btype='highpass',analog=True, ftype='cheby2')

s_filtered = lfilter(b, a, data)
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 3))
plt.plot(data, label='original')
_ = plt.plot(s_filtered ,label='filtered')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But i'm getting :

[image]

If you want the file with the signal, here it  is:
https://easyupload.io/j5shnb

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Comment: ECG signals arent supposed to drop the voltage ( look at what's happening between [2000,4000] ) . It's supposed to be a straight line .